# iOS app update - CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion

Tags: iphone, ios, plist, itunes, bundle

My currect iOS app in Appstore market has follwing bundle Versions.

CFBundleVersion 10301 
CFBundleShortVersionString 1.3.0

Im going to update my app this week 
and my version # are

CFBundleVersion 2.1.7 
CFBundleShortVersionString 2.1.7

My doubt here is

Current CFBundleVersion 10301 
New CFBundleVersion 2.1.7

is this correct?

Can I change the format of CFBundleVersion  in my new version

Answer (score 8):

Must update the version should be high.10301 because it was an older version must also complete a version higher than 10301.

your CFBundleVersion must be set 10301 higher.

2.1.7 is lower than 10301. of the binary file generate to fail. The update must be higher than the previous version

you'll don't worry about it. If you simply think that is the build number.

---

**What is the difference between each version?**

---

**iTunes Connect Version**

iTunes Connect Version is the version number shown in the App Store; This must be a pure version number like 1.0.1

**CFBundleVersion**

CFBundleVersion is doesn't need to be a real version number. This can be something like 12345 or 1.2.3 (Build 12345AB). This is shown in the About window for Mac OS X apps for example and is often more a "Build Number" than a "Version Number".

**CFBundleShortVersionString**

CFBundleShortVersionString is used as the real version number. This must be the same string as used for the version in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

- **CFBundleVersion** stands for the build number
- **CFBundleShortVersionString** stands for the version number

For the details, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921249/936957)

Answer (score 1):

As i know as long as you're binary CFBundleVersion is match with the one that you submitted in new version of you're app in itunesconnect there should be no problem.