# CFBundleVersion must be a period separated list of at most three non-negative integers (WARNING ITMS-9000)

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store-connect

I'm getting this warning when trying to submit my app:

[image]

> WARNING ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key
>   CFBundleVersion [3.3.9.2014.08.20] int the info.plist file must be a
>   period separated list of at most **three** non-negative integers."

This is the first time I'm seeing this after a lot of submissions with that versioning format.

Is something changed regarding CFBundleVersion ?

I'm guessing the **three** wasn't always there? or apple just started warning us about it?

From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364):

> CFBundleVersion
>
> CFBundleVersion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the build version
>   number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or
>   unreleased) of the bundle. The build version number should be a string
>   comprised of three non-negative, period-separated integers with the
>   first integer being greater than zero. The string should only contain
>   numeric (0-9) and period (.) characters. Leading zeros are truncated
>   from each integer and will be ignored (that is, 1.02.3 is equivalent
>   to 1.2.3). This key is not localizable.

**Edit:**

Apparently CFBundleVersion was changed as you can see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120519210552/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/web/20120516081816/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html).
It's a shame that I need to search WayBackMachine for something like that while Apple's "Document Revision History" says nothing about it.

Comment: This error has definitely existed in the past: https://www.google.com/search?q="at+most+three+non-negative+integers"&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A1%2F1%2F2014 but why it's back now is certainly a mystery.

Comment: You are right, thanks. Right now its a warning. I'm hoping that the submission won't get rejected for this.

Comment: Any progress on this submittal? I also got the same warning (for 1.0.4.3435) even though I've used this format in the past with no warnings ...

Comment: Still waiting for review. I'll report back on any updates.

Comment: Me too. Fall in the same warning (for 1.1.826.1). Since 3 years, we submit apps with the version numbering policy [Major].[Minor].[BuildNumber].[Revision]

Comment: Just had this error too. Amusingly they haven't fixed the email, which still says that "1.4.0.0.0.0.5" would be valid

Comment: This existed in the past (as an error and not a warning) but only for the app version in iTunes (CFBundleShortVersionString) and not for CFBundleVersion, This is very annoying but for now it seems they approve apps with this warning... (may change in the near future)

Comment: My app was approved. From now on I guess we'll use three non-negative integers.

Comment: Looks like they made this an error now :/ See my answer for details

Comment: As of Oct. 11, 2016, the CFBundleVersion still must be a period separated list of at most three non-negative integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently CFBundleVersion was changed as you can see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120519210552/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/web/20120516081816/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html).
It's a shame that I need to search WayBackMachine for something like that while Apple's "Document Revision History" says nothing about it.

Answer (score 13):

This happened to a framework I was using from Cocoapods, here is how I fixed it:

You need to find non-standard CFBundleShortVersionString in info.plist file. I searched through all of them and found this in one of the repos:

```
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>HEAD based on 1.0</string>
```

Changed it to this:

```
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
  <string>1.0</string>
```

and it worked

This method, created by Cocoapods developers also works:

https://github.com/Jonge/Cocoapods-frameworks-version-number-fix

Comment: Found the same issue. Make sure to check your cocoapods!

Comment: Changing this manually doesn't seem to be handy. I suggest using a script posted below.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like Apple has taken this a step further and made this an error (not sure when this happened, but I'm using Xcode 6). Attempting to submit an application with a `CFBundleShortVersionString` with more than 2 decimal points will result in an archive's submission to iTunes Connect to fail now.

You now **must** have a `CFBundleShortVersionString` like `1.0`, `4.5.2`, etc. to successfully submit your applications. Could be a bit annoying, but I suppose it makes sense.

[image: Error]

Comment: Using the XCode 8.2 Organizer I've got problems using ONLY two ditigs and one point (1.0). The Organizer told me about some signing problems. The problems dissolved when I changed the version to 1.0.0 ...

Answer (score 6):

The recommended best-practice is to now use separate values for `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion`

- 3-component max for `CFBundleShortVersionString` (ex: 4.2.3)
- A build number `CFBundleVersion`

The `CFBundleShortVersionString` is the version shown on the App Store.
The `CFBundleVersion` will need to change for every build you upload.

Ex: if you upload a new version (4.2.3) for review on iTunesConnect and if it gets rejected. You will need to resubmit a new build for the same version number (`CFBundleShortVersionString` = 4.2.3) with a different `CFBundleVersion` value

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `CocoaPods`, add this script to `Podfile` to handle non-numeric bundle versions:

```
# fix for non numeric CocoaPods versions
# https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4421#issuecomment-151804311
post_install do |installer|
  plist_buddy = "/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    plist = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target}/Info.plist"
    original_version = `#{plist_buddy} -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "#{plist}"`.strip
    changed_version = original_version[/(\d+\.){1,2}(\d+)?/]
    unless original_version == changed_version
      puts "Fix version of Pod #{target}: #{original_version} => #{changed_version}"
      `#{plist_buddy} -c "Set CFBundleShortVersionString #{changed_version}" "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target}/Info.plist"`
    end
  end
end
```

Example output for ReactiveCocoa 4:

```
Installing ReactiveCocoa (4.0.4-alpha-1)
(...)
Fix version of Pod ReactiveCocoa: 4.0.4-alpha-1 => 4.0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the Same issue as-

> Blockquote

ERROR ITMS-90058: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [ms-08-23] in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."

> Blockquote

There after I went and searched with every Third party framework Plist and in SAP libraries I found  **Bundle version** as **[ms-08-23]** .
I changed it to a format of three non-negative integer **i.e** **3.0.0** , I changed it in every Framework of SAP - ***IT Worked***.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the error, then search following the CFBundleVersion, in your case search: 3.3.9.2014.08.20 then change it to right version like 3.3.9 or 3.4.0,…(it must greater than the old version)