# iOS App Upload is getting CFBundleShortVersionString error message

Tags: ios, app-store

So I am trying to upload my app to the App store, and I am getting this error message.

ERROR ITMS-90060: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString 'HEAD based on 1.0' in the Info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."

If I open the log it gives me, you can clearly see the version short string is correct.

```
<software_assets apple_id="456805313"
        bundle_short_version_string="27.1.1"
        bundle_version="3221"
        ....
</software_assets>
```

What am I missing?!?

Comment: The issue is the '27' in 27.1.1, It needs to be single digit. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418798/cfbundleversion-must-be-a-period-separated-list-of-at-most-three-non-negative-in

Also, if you are using Cocoapods, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33375436/1740354

Comment: 27 wasn't the issue but your link led me to the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check any 3rd party frameworks you've used. There are reports floating around of xcode tripping over bundle_short_version_string included in 3rd party resources pulled into the main project. For example:

[CFBundleVersion must be a period separated list of at most three non-negative integers (WARNING ITMS-9000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25418798/cfbundleversion-must-be-a-period-separated-list-of-at-most-three-non-negative-in)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23581

Comment: That was it.  The comment above helped lead me to this page which iterates through the Pods and updates them. https://github.com/Jonge/Cocoapods-frameworks-version-number-fix

Answer (score 1):

I have used pods in my project, In the `info.plist` of `pod SVWebViewController` `CFBundleShortVersion` was not in standard way.
You need to find non-standard `CFBundleShortVersionString` in `info.plist` file. I searched through all of them and found this in one of the repo

**Before**

```
Bundle versions string, short => Head is 0.1.2
```

**After**

```
Bundle versions string, short => 0.1.2
```

After correcting `CFBundleShortVersion` everything worked fine.