# Can I submit a new app version in iTunes Connect without cancelling the former that is "Pending developer release"?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an App in iTunes Connect that has the status **Pending developer release** , i.e. it has been approved by Apple's review team and now I can release it manually whenever I want. (Note, this is the initial launch, i.e. there is currently no vesion of that app available in the App Store).

My question now is if it is possible to already submit a new version in iTunes Connect without cancelling the already approved version, by *cancelling* I precisely mean *lose the opportunity to release it to the App Store*.

Comment: Are you trying to cheat the Apple review process?. If Apple provide such an option to replace a new build with "Pending Developer Release" one then just imagine what can happen if a hacker do so by putting his virus or malware into his new build and replace the approved one?.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I am not asking to replace the version in that the new shouldn't get a review! I just wanted to know whether a new version can go into review while the old one is not yet released to the store :)

Comment: I always appreciate comments when being downvoted

Comment: A huge tip is that: click on the "developer rejected" panel. You will see the build (you want to delete). Incredibly, the **TINY ICON TO DELETE IT, ONLY APPEARS WHEN YOU MOUSE OVER THE INVISIBLE ICON - it's to your right.** (It's one of the red "stop sign" icons, like a "-" sign.) Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can only have **one version of the app in the release process**.

The only you can do is change the build of that version ([Changing builds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW11)) while the version is not yet submitted for review. But, if the review has happened, you will need to reject the current binary, **requiring the review to happen again**.

---

Note that:

[image]

Comment: you mean to say I need to cancel the release.. and then change the build and then again apply for review?

Answer (score 4):

There are two things I interpreted from the documentation that are possible once your app has already gone through the review process in a situation such as yours.

1. Release the app, remove it from sale to users, "replace" it without needing to review again
2. Remove build from review and start the process over from the beginning

Apple's documentation isn't entirely clear on this, easy to misinterpret, confusing and/or possible Apple is confused themselves. In the section "[Changing an App's Status](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW18)" it mentions that if you have an issue with a "version" of your app that is released you can remove it from sale and then "replace" it without having to go through the review process again. I'm guessing Apple means "update" instead of "version" here, although it's probably wrong to assume anything in this particular circumstance. According to another stackoverflow member I recently had a discussion with this about, regardless if it's an "update" or new "version" you would need to go through the review process again from the beginning to actually "replace" it, which does seem more logical. I trust they are correct, and Apple's choice of words in this particular circumstance is incredibly poor.

Here are the two processes summarized:

### Remove the app from sale to users

<sub>*To remove your app from sale on the store*:</sub>

1. Open the App Details page for the app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App.
2. Click Pricing and Availability.
3. Select Remove from Sale from the Availability section.

> Whether for marketing reasons or because you find an issue with a
>   version of an app that’s on the store, you can remove an app from the
>   store. You can replace the app on the store without requiring the app
>   to be reviewed again.

### Removing a Build from Review

You can remove the build you’ve submitted if its status is any of the following:

- Waiting For Export Compliance
- Waiting For Review
- In Review
- Pending Developer Release
- Pending Apple Release

<sub>*To remove your build from review:*</sub>

1. Open the App Details page for the app, as described in Creating an iTunes Connect Record for an App.
2. Select the platform version you want to remove. Above the app’s metadata, this message appears: “You can only edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review.” Click “remove this version from review.”

> Removing a build removes your app version from Apple’s review queue
>   and changes its status to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your
>   app, the review process starts over from the beginning. Only users
>   with the Admin, Technical, or App Manager role can remove a build from
>   review.

↳ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW17

Comment: Do I only need to increase `CFBundleVersion` or do I need to increase `CFBundleShortVersionString` too if I want to submit an update (before official release)? I assume that Apple always will again check the complete app in either case (remove from sales/rejected app from developer)?

Comment: @testing: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19726988/499581) and the answers for the explanation and differences between the two. Basically `CFBundleVersion` should always increment for each build you submit, which is required. When you are ready to release the new version you can then increment the `CFBundleShortVersionString` to match.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding the question from this thread: Can I cancel the already approved app, which is in *Pending Developer Release*, then submit a new version, but only update `CFBundleVersion`? So that I keep the old version the users sees?