# Submit new version of iOS app to itunes connect without releasing the first

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I recently pushed a version of my app for the first time through the iTunes Connect review process - it unexpectedly got a approved first time - but we didn't release it.

We now want to add a new version/update to the same record - but to do this do we have to cancel the existing 'Pending Developer Release'?

And does this mean we have to go through the same whole process again?

Comment: Yes, each new version you release needs to be reviewed and approved by Apple

Comment: @Paulw11: Actually that's not entirely true... you can release the app and remove it from sale, and then can replace the app on the store without requiring the app to be reviewed again. (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34300845/499581))

Comment: If they want to release a new version/binary (which is my understanding of the question) then review is required.  Simply re-releasing the same version is not releasing a new version

Comment: @Paulw11: I interpreted the question more as they are meaning an update rather than a new version. If it's a new version then yes, it's entirely different.

Comment: You can update the meta data and price without a re-review, but apart from that I don't know what other sort of update you would be talking about aside from a new version

Comment: @Paulw11: Read the last item under [Changing an App's Status](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW18), that's where the information comes from. Unless Apple's meaning of version is something different than ours, it seems like it's possible.

Comment: For clarity that sentence should read "You can replace the **the same version** of the app on the store without requiring the app to be reviewed again".  While the first sentence of the paragraph refers to removing a version if it has an issue, it simply isn't the case that you can release a new version without review, even if you removed a version because it had an issue

Comment: @Paulw11: But they say "replace" in there... how could that be the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98039/discussion-between-paulw11-and-lll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You'll have to reject the binary, re-submit a new binary, then send it off to Apple to for review. It sucks, I know.