# Phonegap - The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, info.plist, application-loader

I have followed all steps to generate the `.ipa file` and went to upload it using the Application Loader but kept getting the following error:

```
The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleVersion key.
 The Info.plist in the package must contain the CFBundleShortVersionString key.
```

Here's Hello World-Info.plist file containg all the info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>icon.png</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon.png</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
        <array>
          <string>icon-small</string>
          <string>icon-40</string>
          <string>icon-50</string>
          <string>icon-76</string>
          <string>icon-60</string>
          <string>icon</string>
          <string>icon@2x</string>
          <string>icon-72</string>
          <string>icon-72@2x</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
        <false/>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.phonegap.helloworld</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>11</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>11</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile~ipad</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

What needs to be fixed/added so I can upload my application?!

Comment: What do you have under TargetName -> General -> Identity?

Comment: @sloik Where can I find that?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there needs to be a `config.xml` in the `www/` directory which wasn't there by default from the beginning.

In the widget tag, the following should be specified:

```
version="1.0.6" ios-CFBundleVersion="201406097"
```

where the version number should be changed everytime you wish to deploy an new update on the app store. I read that you can write a script that takes care of the version so you don't have to change it manually each time but didn't try it.

For the `CFBundleVersion` you could check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726988/what-values-should-i-use-for-cfbundleversion-and-cfbundleshortversionstring) which explains it. But you won't need to change it when deploying.

Answer (score 12):

Add after first opening of the < dict >

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Replace 1.0 with the version of the application you want.The funny thing is that those should be generated for you any time you are changing anything in the TargetName -> General -> Identity :)

**Edit:** added a image where those setting are displayd

[image: Where to find those settings]

Comment: That is a phonegap app so I only get the .ipa file after building it. Any idea how can I proceed?!
I added the above but still nothing works.

Comment: You did not mention that this is a phonegap app :) Can't help you with that sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

just check their should not contain white space at or at end in Version and Build number