# Kotlin Multiplatform: Set version in Info.plist

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, info.plist

I have a Kotlin Multiplatform project and build it for iOS with
`assembleXCFramwork`

Everything works fine and the module is created. But currently I don't see any version in the `Info.plist` file.
In `build.gradle.kts` I set a version like:
`version = "1.1.9"`

Is it possible to somehow write this version automatically into the `Plist.info` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for asking. I guess I just found it here:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-build-native-binaries.html#export-dependencies-to-binaries

Yes it works with this setting

```
binaries {
    framework {
        binaryOption("bundleVersion", "1.1.9")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Additionally, it's worth noting that `bundleShortVersionString` is the version number ("Version" in Xcode) and `bundleVersion` is the build number ("Build" in Xcode). Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921249/1470581 and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring